# A way to pull more in-depth user object data from the Exchange server using GraphAPI?

Tags: python, exchange-server, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working on a Python script that pulls user data from AD and the Graph API (v1.0) to perform "health checks" on users experiencing account issues (mailbox problems, provisioning, etc.).

I'm currently looking for a Graph-equivalent of the PowerShell command:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName MAIL_ADDRESS@domain.com).errors[0].ErrorDetail.objecterrors.errorrecord.ErrorDescription
```

I've spent some time scouring the GraphAPI documentation and even poked through the template for the response object itself, but wasn't able to find any user object attributes being returned beyond just the high-level face value ones (things like UPN, phone number, etc. Extension attributes were the only remotely in-depth attributes I could find and even those weren't terribly detailed).

Does anyone know of a Graph equivalent for this Powershell command, or even if there might be some other way to pull back some deeper user object data from the Exchange server, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Below link you can find the list of operation you can perform on Azure AD

[Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog)

For getting an user detail , you can call the below api from powershell:

GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version

To call it from powershell, you can follow the below code snippet, just replace the  below api url with User specific one.

```js
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://main.b2cadmin.ext.azure.com/api/trustframework?tenantId=$AzureSubscriptionTenantId&overwriteIfExists=$overwriteIfExists" -Method POST -Body $strBody -ContentType "application/xml" -Headers $htHeaders -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Which can return a json object with following details:

```js
"odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/@Element",
  "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
  "objectType": "User",
  "objectId": "13addec1-c5ae-47f5-a1fe-202be14b1570",
  "deletionTimestamp": null,
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "signInNames": [],
  "assignedLicenses": [
    {
      "disabledPlans": [],
      "skuId": "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"
    }
  ],
  "assignedPlans": [
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2014-10-14T02:54:04Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "service": "exchange",
      "servicePlanId": "efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0"
    },
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2014-10-14T02:54:04Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "service": "SharePoint",
      "servicePlanId": "5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72"
    },
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2014-10-14T02:54:04Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "service": "SharePoint",
      "servicePlanId": "e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014"
    },
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2014-10-14T02:54:04Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline",
      "servicePlanId": "0feaeb32-d00e-4d66-bd5a-43b5b83db82c"
    },
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2014-10-14T02:54:04Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "service": "MicrosoftOffice",
      "servicePlanId": "43de0ff5-c92c-492b-9116-175376d08c38"
    },
    {
      "assignedTimestamp": "2014-10-14T02:54:04Z",
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "service": "RMSOnline",
      "servicePlanId": "bea4c11e-220a-4e6d-8eb8-8ea15d019f90"
    }
  ],
  "city": "Tulsa",
  "country": "United States",
  "creationType": null,
  "department": "Sales & Marketing",
  "dirSyncEnabled": null,
  "displayName": "Garth Fort",
  "facsimileTelephoneNumber": null,
  "givenName": "Garth",
  "immutableId": null,
  "jobTitle": "Web Marketing Manager",
  "lastDirSyncTime": null,
  "mail": "garthf@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com",
  "mailNickname": "garthf",
  "mobile": null,
  "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
  "otherMails": [],
  "passwordPolicies": "None",
  "passwordProfile": null,
  "physicalDeliveryOfficeName": "20/1101",
  "postalCode": "74133",
  "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
  "provisionedPlans": [
    {
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "provisioningStatus": "Success",
      "service": "exchange"
    },
    {
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "provisioningStatus": "Success",
      "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline"
    },
    {
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "provisioningStatus": "Success",
      "service": "SharePoint"
    },
    {
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "provisioningStatus": "Success",
      "service": "SharePoint"
    },
    {
      "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
      "provisioningStatus": "Success",
      "service": "MicrosoftOffice"
    }
  ],
  "provisioningErrors": [],
  "proxyAddresses": [
    "SMTP:garthf@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com"
  ],
  "sipProxyAddress": "garthf@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com",
  "state": "OK",
  "streetAddress": "7633 E. 63rd Place, Suite 300",
  "surname": "Fort",
  "telephoneNumber": "+1 918 555 0101",
  "usageLocation": "US",
  "userPrincipalName": "garthf@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com",
  "userType": "Member"
}
```

Here is the python equivalent code for calling the same api:

```
########### Python 2.7 #############
import httplib, urllib, base64

# OAuth2 is required to access this API. For more information visit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks

headers = {
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
    # Specify values for the following required parameters
    'api-version': '1.6',
})

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('graph.windows.net')
    # Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...}) and request body if needed
    conn.request("GET", "/myorganization/users/{user_id}?%s" % params, "", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

####################################

########### Python 3.2 #############
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

# OAuth2 is required to access this API. For more information visit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks

headers = {
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Specify values for the following required parameters
    'api-version': '1.6',
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('graph.windows.net')
    # Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...}) and request body if needed
    conn.request("GET", "/myorganization/users/{user_id}?%s" % params, "", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

####################################
```

Hope this will help you with what you are looking for.
Let me know if you want to call it from powershell, i can help you with the command.